# Determining values to convert square wave to sine wave at low frequency

Tags: circuit-design, filter, low-pass, passive-filter

For a project I am working on, I have a 1Hz square wave coming from a real time clock, and need to convert it into a sinusoidal wave to pulse LEDs. After some googling and playing around with simulations I came up with the circuit below. The 1Hz square wave is connected at the net labelled SQUARE and then filtered:
[image: Triple RC Filter and NPN transistor]

My question now is how do I determine values for the passives to effectively filter out the higher frequencies and get the single sine wave I want? I got the values you see here from messing with a simulator, but I don't understand how to derive them analytically.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 200k is far too large for Rb when I expect   Rc ~ 220 , thus Rc/Rb =1k should be around 20 max. unless superbeta switches are chosen.  Please define linear sine output when you have a very non-linear amp. Since current ? not sine voltage!  try current feedback.

Comment: What is the input driver?

Comment: The input is coming from an MCP7940M real time clock, it's a 1Hz square wave with an open drain, pulled up to the supply voltage through R1.

Comment: You cannot possibly design any filter without knowing the source impedance of drain R  , Voltage and same for output LED, Vf, If and sine distortion tolerance

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I might just use a microcontroller to create the wave instead, after looking at how complex it will be to figure this out.

Comment: Not complex for me to design , but hard for you to specify everything. That's what you need to learn.

Comment: @Treeaza What are you trying to achieve with the LEDs? It's not clear to me. Do you want some kind of varying intensity? Or?

Comment: I'm just trying to make them fade in and out.

Comment: @Treeaza Thought so. This means you really want an exponential increase in current and then an exponential fall in current. A linear increase in base voltage followed by a linear decrease in base voltage (relative to emitter voltage) achieves this goal, using the collector as the current source. You want to turn the square wave into a ramp up, then down -- a triangle wave. More like that. Does it need to turn them completely off and then completely on? (I think we recently covered this somewhere on EESE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square wave has odd harmonics 3f,5f,7f at levels of ~ -10dB,-14dB, -17dB ..

A 1st order filter is -6dB/octave and 3f is 2 octaves above f or -12dB more than the -10db harmonic @ 3f.

Triangular Current will not be much different to the eye than sinusoidal as the eye is logarithmic .

[You might try something like this.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.00035%2013.097415321081861%2050%205%2050%0At%20288%20112%20320%20112%200%20-1%202.350401457509017%20-0.6010048206914913%2050%0Aw%20320%2080%20320%2096%203%0Aw%20320%20224%20384%20224%200%0Ar%20256%20112%20224%20112%200%20330%0Ar%20320%2080%20320%2032%200%204%0Aw%20256%2032%20320%2032%200%0AR%20256%2032%20256%200%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20320%20160%20320%20208%200%20100%0Aw%20192%20160%20160%20160%202%0Ar%2064%20160%2064%2032%200%201000%0Aw%20320%20128%20384%20128%200%0Aw%20256%20112%20288%20112%201%0Aw%20320%20224%20320%20208%201%0Ag%20224%20176%20224%20192%200%0Ax%20235%20162%20256%20165%204%2016%20Q1%0Ax%20332%20113%20353%20116%204%2016%20Q2%0AR%2032%20176%200%20176%200%202%201%202.5%200%200%200.5%0A34%20old-default-ledR%200%202.235e-18%200%202.2%200%0A162%20320%20128%20320%20160%202%20old-default-ledR%201%200%200%200.02%0A34%20spice-defaultG%200%201e-11%2015%205.2%203%0A162%20384%20128%20384%20160%202%20spice-defaultG%200%201%200%200.02%0Ar%20384%20160%20384%20208%200%20100%0A162%20448%20128%20448%20160%202%20spice-defaultG%200%200%201%200.02%0A403%20368%20272%20432%20320%200%2018_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.01082957700184741_0_2_18_3%0A403%20288%20272%20352%20320%200%207_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.019546022161848874_0_2_7_3%0Ar%20448%20160%20448%20208%200%2050%0Aw%20384%20224%20448%20224%200%0Aw%20384%20128%20448%20128%202%0Af%2032%20176%2064%20176%2032%201.5%2010%0Ag%2064%20192%2064%20224%200%0Aw%2064%2032%20256%2032%200%0Ar%20112%20160%20160%20160%200%2010000%0At%20192%20160%20224%20160%200%201%20-1.2383563931762684%200.6475437997965611%20100%0A209%20224%20112%20160%20112%200%200.000039999999999999996%201.2383563931762684%201%0Aw%20448%20224%20448%20208%201%0Aw%20384%20224%20384%20208%201%0Ag%20384%20224%20384%20240%200%0Aw%20224%20112%20224%20144%202%0Aw%20112%20160%2064%20160%200%0Aw%20160%20112%20160%20160%200%0Ar%20256%20112%20256%2032%200%2080%0A403%20448%20272%20512%20320%200%2020_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.01809750138038736_0_2_20_3%0Ab%2096%20-16%20498%20249%200%0Ao%2035%2064%200%2012546%202.0848815649174535%200.0001%200%202%2035%203%20Q1-C%0Ao%2010%2064%200%2012546%204.0433581042772335%200.0001%201%202%2010%203%20Q2-C%0Ao%200%2064%202%2012547%200.0001%200.048474264519738394%202%201%20Q2-current%0A)

[image]

Then you can always try sine PWM control using a FET switch with current limiting R for each LED.

But the hardest thing it seems to learn is how to define a design spec (before attempting to design it) including the LED datasheets with **inputs, Processess and Outputs** in a point form **Hierarchical** format.

**IBM used to call this, the HIPO format for design specs.**
Simple, Elegant, Complete, Measurable and Verifiable.

If you graduate and do design/test work, you must learn to create Design Specs then Design Verification Tests ( DVT plans and reports) based on these simple specs and record it. This is how Japanese Engineers think and how I did it in Winnipeg and Silicon valley. in early 80's as well as an Aerospace Engineer in late 70's.

**If it meets spec. It's perfect.** But it has to be a good specs with above Design values, budget and design time. (always double estimated design time)

Comment: Any questions?.

Comment: No, thank you for all your help. I understand now how my question was very ambiguous, it hadn't occurred to me how much component selection would impact the filter design. I'm only a couple of years into my degree, and I often forget to use a proper design process with my projects, this is something I will need to work on in future.

Comment: Rule of Thumb is for same voltages Rb/Rc ~ 10 to 30.